# How to print text while netcat is listening at a port?

Tags: python, bash, sockets, networking, scripting

I am writing a small chat app with python using bash commands. I'm using nc to accomplish this but I want to be able to append a username before the user's message. How do I go about doing this without breaking the connection?
The command I'm using to connect is just

`nc -l -p 1234 -q 0`
and the desired outcome is that when the person sends something it would look like: `<User1> Hello`

Thank you!

Comment: Going to need some more info.... How is this a python question

Comment: Is this part of a script? Have you tried something that did break the connection? If so, let's see it. If not, you really should have before asking here. Not trying to discourage you from asking questions here, just saying that you should always show you've made an effort to answer your own question first.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
nc -l -p 1234 -q 0 <<< "$LOGNAME Hello!"
```

Answer (score 0):

its hard to understand the context and the applications structure, but i would assume that putting the connection in a separate thread would help. So that the connection is always open and the messages can be processed in preferred fashion.