# how to netcat in listen mode prints to stdout when -c option is in use

Tags: linux, shell, netcat

I put `netcat -l -p 80` into terminal. Then open http://localhost/ in web browser. Now `netcat` shows the header of the request in stdout. All fine.

But if I use `netcat` with the `-c` option `netcat` does not print anymore to stdout.

How can I get `netcat -l -p 80 -c uname` to print to stdout?

Maybe via the `-o file` option via file descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

After this
[Redirect process stdin and stdout to netcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311287/redirect-process-stdin-and-stdout-to-netcat)
and that
[How to print text while netcat is listening at a port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814272/how-to-print-text-while-netcat-is-listening-at-a-port)

I installed `sudo apt install ncat`

and this solves my problem:

`ncat -l -p 80 <<< "hello"`